# RichEdit 8 and Direct2D/DirectWrite

Tags: directx, richtextbox, direct2d, richedit

Help me please, as in Windows 10 standard RichEdit control switch to DirectWrite mode. I need RichEdit to draw text using DirectWrite. I get a pointer to ITextDocument2, but what should I do next? Thank you in advance!

```
CRichEditCtrl m_richEdit;
m_richEdit.Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE, CRect(10,10,400,270), this, 100);

CComPtr<IRichEditOle> richEditOle;
::SendMessage(m_richEdit.m_hWnd, EM_GETOLEINTERFACE, 0, (LPARAM)&richEditOle);

CComPtr<ITextDocument2> document;
HRESULT hr = richEditOle->QueryInterface( _uuidof(ITextDocument2), (void **)&document);
```

Comment: When asking questions, you need to add some context and even code.

Comment: The question is what do you want to do exactly? The fact that they switched to DirectWrite should not be visible from existing API.

Comment: Didn't rich edit stop at [version 4.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787873(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/murrays/2013/09/07/richedit-8-feature-additions/